# Finding independence of two variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, statistical-inference

I am trying the following problem:

> Let $(X_1, Y_1)\ and\ (X_2, Y_2)$ be random points on the plane such that $X_1, X_2, Y_1, and\ Y_2$ are independent
>   $N(µ, σ^2)$. Let $D^2\ $ denote the squared distance between the two points.
>
> Determine whether or not $D^2\ and\ T =\frac{1}{4}
> (X1 + X2 + Y1 + Y2)\  $ are independent.

Here I found $D^2\ is\ 2\sigma^2\chi_2^2\ andand\ T\ is\ N(\mu, \frac {\sigma^2}{4}) $ distribution. But I could not understand which path i have to use?

Comment: Here is a somewhat simpler, but closely related, problem. Let $(X, Y)$ be a point with IID normal coordinates. Show that $X + Y$ and $X - Y$ are independent. More generally, look at the proof the the mean $\bar X$ and the variance $S^2$ based on a random sample from a normal distribution are (probabilistically) independent RVs (even though they are not _functionally_ independent, because $\bar X$ is used in the definition of $S^2$).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.